# как убрать синюю полоску в intelijidea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

как убрать синюю полоску в intelijidea
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую именно? Пишите развернутые вопросы.

Comment: зайди на ссылку увидешь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это дебаггер сделайте стоп он исчезнет у вас одновременно работает несколько app

Answer (score 0):

File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Debugger 
`Execution point`